# Getting Add-in to Display on Shared Calendar On Windows Client?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Hi all
Having an issue with an add-in I developed for Outlook using the newest Office API set of 1.8.  I added the requisite `<SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>` to load the plug-in on the ribbon of the Shared Calendar portion of the Appointment tab and it works on all instances of client/OWA except Windows. 
 
    In Windows the system does not show any loading errors, issues from the app, etc. but does not load.  While in the OS X client the system works as intended.  Loading in OWA works as well, but just not in Windows.
    I can provide the full manifest though the needed portion should only be the "SupportsSharedFolders" being enabled to get it into the system.  Anyone else having this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the manifest file so that we can try to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am actually going to close this one.  I ended up figuring out the issue and going to put it as the answer.  Long story long, for me at least, was the Outlook versioning needs to be at least 1912 for it to show up for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All for whomever might be running into this same issue:
   The 'fix' for this was making sure the versioning of Outlook matched the minimum of version 1912 on the Monthly track.  Any less, 1908 was not working, the system does not load the most current Outlook/Office API 1.8 so does not recognize the Shared Calendar access for add-ins.